# Javasacript Countdown timer in Days, Hours, Minute, Seconds

Tags: javascript, php, timer, countdowntimer

I'm trying to create a time-based count down clock. It is not based upon current_dates. The initial time that will be pulled will be from a separate php file. This will be for a browser based-game. When someone clicks the button to initiate this script. it will check if certain requirements are met and if so then this script will initiate. Based upon the level of the object it will pull the initial timer for that proceeding level. Hope that makes sense. Anyhow I based the timer script off of the first code I provide.

This script only accounts for minutes and seconds. I modified it to include days and hours as well. Somewhere in the process I have messed up and the script doesn't even work at all.  I'm also not quite sure if this would be the best method to calculate this. So, if you have a cleaner method at doing this please share. Thank you in advance.

This script is based off of a minutes / seconds script I saw. Here's the original source:

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
   var seconds = 60;
   function secondPassed() {
   var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
   var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
   if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
      remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
   }
   document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
   if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
   } else {
    seconds--;
   }
   }
   var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

Here is the modified script that I am trying to include days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<script>
     var current_level = 93578;

     function timer() {

        var days = Math.round(current_level/86400);
        var remainingDays = Math.round(current_level - (days * 86400));

        if (days <= 0){
             days = current_level;
        }

        var hours = Math.round(remainingDays/3600);
        var remainingHours = Math.round(remainingDays - (hours * 3600));

        if (hours >= 24){
             hours = 23;
        }

        var minutes = Math.round(remainingHours/60);
        var remainingMinutes = Math.round(remainingHours - (minutes * 60));

        if (minutes >= 60) {
             minutes = 59;
        }

        var seconds = Math.round(remainingMinutes/60);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (seconds == 0) {
             clearInterval(countdownTimer);
             document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
        }
     }
     var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I finally got back to looking at this and re-wrote the code and this works like a charm.

```js
var upgradeTime = 172801;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
  var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
  var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
  var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
  var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: With javascript its much better to post working demos.

Comment: This help me so much

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use the jquery countdown timer integration. It is simple and having number of options to display in different formats. Since I am fairly new to JS as well, this was the easiest way I found to get a count/timer.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Once again this snippet is for pulling dates not a set variable as displayed in the original source code in seconds and in the modified version as current_level

Answer (score 0):

Here is my worked out and tested example, based on your code

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<script>
     var current_level = 3002;

     function timer() {

        var days = Math.floor(current_level/86400);
        var remainingDays = current_level - (days * 86400);

        //if (days <= 0){
        //    days = current_level;
        //}

        var hours = Math.floor(remainingDays/3600);
        var remainingHours = remainingDays - (hours * 3600);

        //if (hours >= 24){
        //     hours = 23;
        //}

        var minutes = Math.floor(remainingHours/60);
        var remainingMinutes = remainingHours - (minutes * 60);

        //if (minutes >= 60) {
        //     minutes = 59;
        //}

        var seconds = remainingMinutes;

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        //if (seconds == 0) {
        //    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        //     document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
        //}

        current_level--;
     }
     var countdownTimer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code will help you deal with the issue of handling multiple timer on the single page**

```js
    var seconds_inputs =  document.getElementsByClassName('deal_left_seconds');
    var total_timers = seconds_inputs.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++){
        var str_seconds = 'seconds_'; var str_seconds_prod_id = 'seconds_prod_id_';
        var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');
        var cal_seconds = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('value');

        eval('var ' + str_seconds + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + cal_seconds + ';');
        eval('var ' + str_seconds_prod_id + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + seconds_prod_id + ';');
    }
    function timer() {
        for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++) {
            var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');

            var days = Math.floor(eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) / 24 / 60 / 60);
            var hoursLeft = Math.floor((eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id)) - (days * 86400));
            var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
            var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) % 60;

            function pad(n) {
                return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
            }
            document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(days);
            document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(hours);
            document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(minutes);
            document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(remainingSeconds);

            if (eval('seconds_'+ seconds_prod_id) == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(0);
            } else {
                var value = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id);
                value--;
                eval('seconds_' + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + value + ';');
            }
        }
    }

    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="deal_left_seconds" data-value="1" value="10">
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="date box"> <span class="key" id="deal_days_1">00</span> <span class="value">DAYS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="hour box"> <span class="key" id="deal_hrs_1">00</span> <span class="value">HRS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="minutes box"> <span class="key" id="deal_min_1">00</span> <span class="value">MINS</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper hidden-md">
    <div class="seconds box"> <span class="key" id="deal_sec_1">00</span> <span class="value">SEC</span> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Panel = ({ label, n }) => (
  <div className="panel">
    <small>{label}</small>
    <span>{n < 10 ? '0' + n : n}</span>
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = React.useState(86403)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (secondsLeft == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log('Times up!')
      } else {
        setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft - 1)
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  })
  const days = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 24 / 60 / 60)
  const hoursLeft = Math.floor(secondsLeft - days * 86400)
  const hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600)
  const minutesLeft = Math.floor(hoursLeft - hours * 3600)
  const minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60)
  const seconds = secondsLeft % 60

  return (
    <div className="root">
      <Panel label="Days" n={days} />
      <Panel label="Hours" n={hours} />
      <Panel label="Minutes" n={minutes} />
      <Panel label="Seconds" n={seconds} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #444;
}

.panel small {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.panel span {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var upgradeTime = 172801;
var seconds = upgradeTime;
function timer() {
  var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
  var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
  var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
  var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```