# Countdown days, hours, minutes, seconds-made script jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I have a countdown timer with predetermined time?

My code

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var seconds = 6;
            var minutes = 1;

            function calculate() {
                setTimeout(calculate, 1000);
                $('#showDate').html(' expires after ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds ');
                seconds--;
                if (seconds < 0) {
                    seconds = 59;
                    minutes--;
                    if (minutes < 0) {
                        minutes = 0;
                        seconds = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            calculate();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='showDate'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code applies only to minutes and seconds. How can I add hours and days?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Someone can sure help you, but you need to make it easier to do so. For example, the code you provided is unreadable at first glance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javasacript Countdown timer in Days, Hours, Minute, Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182628/javasacript-countdown-timer-in-days-hours-minute-seconds)

Comment: you should be easily able to do this looking of how it's already done with seconds and minutes. what have you tried after this snippet?

Comment: ALL, code is fixed, please see

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on the method that was already being used.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var days = 4;
            var hours = 0;
            var minutes = 0;
            var seconds = 6;

            function calculate() {
                setTimeout(calculate, 1000);
                $('#showDate').html(' expires after ' + days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds ');
                seconds--;
                if (seconds < 0) {
                    seconds = 59;
                    minutes--;
                    if (minutes < 0) {
                        hours--;
                        minutes = 59;
                        if (hours < 0) {
                            days--;
                            hours = 23;
                            if (days < 0) {
                                days = 0;
                                hours = 0;
                                minutes = 0;
                                seconds = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            calculate();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='showDate'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clockdiv">
  expires after <span class="days"></span> day <span class="hours"></span> hours <span class="minutes"></span> minutes <span class="seconds">0</span> seconds
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here you go!

expires after 14 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds