# How to add year to countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have this piece of code and I would like to add "Year" to it. How do I proceed?

```js
 function updateTimer(){
   
    // Get the element to append to
    var counter = document.getElementById("Example");
    // Set the targetDate
    var targetDate = new Date("July 27, 2012 19:30:00");

    var remainingSeconds = ~ ~((targetDate - new Date()) / 1000);
    var remainingTime = {
        "days": remainingSeconds / (60 * 60 * 24),
        "hours": (remainingSeconds % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60),
        "minutes": (remainingSeconds % (60 * 60)) / 60,
        "seconds": remainingSeconds % 60
    };

    var str = "Time left is :: ";
    for (var i in remainingTime) {
        str += ~ ~remainingTime[i] + " " + i + ", ";
    }
    // Store the result in the element
    counter.innerHTML = str.substring(0, str.length - 2);
 }

 // Update the timer every 1 second
 setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="Example"></h1>
```

I tried to do it myself but then it showed Days + Year so for example 10 years would show "10 Years 3650 Days.. etc".

Comment: Your code doesn't even seem to be counting down, it's counting up.

Comment: There are literally dozens of questions about this here on SO and on the internet. There's also no jQuery in this code, so I'm not sure why it's in the tag list...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javasacript Countdown timer in Days, Hours, Minute, Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182628/javasacript-countdown-timer-in-days-hours-minute-seconds)

Comment: Quick and dirty, add: 
"years" :  remainingSeconds / 31540000  // seconds in a year

That will display an estimate since you use "~".

Comment: Try and run it, it will count "down" to your chosen date. I tried adding `"years" : remainingSeconds / 31540000` but it kept displaying hours wrong.