# javascript countdown (d:h:m:s)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, countdown

I use a PHP script to render some remaining time to a view.
Inside this view I use the following JS & HTML code to show to display a "countdown" of the remaining time.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var time = $(this).text().split(':');
      var timestamp = time[0] * 86400 + time[1] * 3600 + time[2] * 60 + time[3] * 1;
      timestamp -= timestamp > 0;
      var days = Math.floor(timestamp / 86400)
      console.log(days);
      var hours = Math.floor((timestamp - days * 86400) / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor( ( (timestamp - days * 86400) - (timestamp - hours * 3600) ) / 60);
      var seconds = (timestamp - days * 86400) - (timestamp - hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
      if (days < 10) {
        days = '0' + days;
      }
      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
      }
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
      }

      $(this).text(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

    });
  }, 1000);
})
```

Value format returned from PHP:

```
<td class="countdown">0:23:4:49</td>
```

There seems to be a problem, while showing this, because when loading the website I get this values inside my console:

```
0
1
NaN
```

Any idea where things go wrong?
How to make the script display more then "one" (24 hours per day) day?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javasacript Countdown timer in Days, Hours, Minute, Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182628/javasacript-countdown-timer-in-days-hours-minute-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Kindy find the fixed minutes and seconds calculator

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var time = $(this).text().split(':');
      var timestamp = time[0] * 86400 + time[1] * 3600 + time[2] * 60 + time[3] * 1;
      timestamp -= timestamp > 0;
      var days = Math.floor(timestamp / 86400)

      var hours = Math.floor((timestamp - (days * 86400) ) / 3600);

      var minutes = Math.floor( (timestamp - ( (days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) )  ) / 60);

      var seconds = Math.floor( (timestamp - ( (days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) )  ) );

      if (days < 10) {
        days = '0' + days;
      }

      hours = hours < 24 ? hours : 23;
      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = '0' + hours;
      }

      minutes = minutes < 60 ? minutes : 59;
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
      }

      seconds = seconds < 60 ? seconds : 59;
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
      }

      $(this).text(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

    });
  }, 1000);
})
```