# JavaScript clock that countsdown hours, mins and seconds only.. not days

Tags: javascript, datetime, clock

I am trying to make a JavaScript clock that countdowns from hours and not days. I have used a nice [countdown JS script from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182628/javasacript-countdown-timer-in-days-hours-minute-seconds) and I am trying to adapt the code to my liking.

My code:

```js
// CLOCK
var end = new Date(2017,4,22,23,59);
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function clock() {

  var now = new Date();
  var distance = end - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
  // get the total day number example, 3 days
  // times that by 3, so 3x24 = 72 hours
  var plus = days * 24;
  // no make the hours + the days, so 4 hours + 72 etc
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour + plus);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

  console.log('Quick! Get the sale while it lasts')
  console.log(+hours + ' hours remaining..');
  console.log(+seconds + ' seconds remaining..');
  console.log(+minutes + ' mins remaining..');

}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('clock()', 1000);
```

If today is the 18th of May, and the end date is the 20th, then the countdown should be around 48hours but it is not working properly. Seems to be using the old 2 days and 15 hours left.. I don't want anything to do with days. I want the hours instead of days.

Any pointers?

Comment: Well, take out the calculation for `days`… the number of hours is simply `distance / _hour`.

Comment: As a remark the comment in the code that says "times that by 3" should be "times that by 24"... but you won't need it anyway as you're getting rid of days. Another remark: if you're showing this to end users, displaying days is certainly more user-friendly; nobody thinks in hours, you'll probably rarely see "only 147 hours left 'til Christmas!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove anything that has a dependency on days (variables, calculations):

```js
var end = new Date('5/22/2017 11:59 PM');
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;

function clock(){
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    var hours = Math.floor(distance / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    console.log('Quick! Get the sale while it lasts')
    console.log(hours + ' hours remaining..');
    console.log(minutes + ' mins remaining..');
    console.log(seconds + ' seconds remaining..');
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

NB: It is considered bad practice to pass a string as first argument to `setInterval`; just pass the function reference.

You will notice that once in while, the counter may jump a second or may display the same number of seconds twice, because `setInterval` does not guarantee that the calls will be *exactly* separated by the given delay. You could counter that effect by calculating when the next second will expire, and provide that dynamic delay to `setTimeout`. Here is also some code to stop the repetition once the target moment has arrived:

```js
// CLOCK
var end = new Date('5/22/2017 11:59 PM');
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;

function clock(){
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance <= 0) {
        console.log('Sorry, sale has ended.')
        return; // stop repeating
    }
    // More precise delay, so you get a tick every second:
    setTimeout(clock, _second*1.5 - now % _second);
    var hours = Math.floor(distance / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    console.log(hours +':' + ('0' + minutes).substr(-2) 
                     + ':' + ('0' + seconds).substr(-2) + ' remaining...');
}

clock(); // Just call it
```

Comment: Thank you, also for the bad practice tip! Why is it bad practice?

Comment: It is bad practice because the string needs to be parsed at run-time, which makes it slower, and if it has a syntax error, it would not surface until that code executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a function:

```
function timestamp() {
   let time = new Date();
   document.getElementById('').innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString();
}
setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
```

In your getElementById() your id name